# Insert correct SSD

Tags: ssd

I want to insert a SSD into Dell Precision 3561.

The specs says that there are *two M.2 2280 slots for solid-state drive 256 GB/512 GB/1
TB/2 TB*.

[image]

I tried to insert a SAMSUNG 860 EVO which could fit the slot. However, either in boot menu nor in Windows the SSD is recognized.

Note: the SSD is not clean: It contains Ubuntu, GRUB and NTFS partitions.

Here is the picture of the slot:
[image]

What do these texts mean: "This SSD requires termal plate" and "no hybryd Optane/SATA?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung EVO 860 is a SATA SSD so it would not work. Try an NVMe SSD like the Kingston A2000 or try a SATA to M.2 and put it in the 2.5in bay.

Comment: What about the "termal plate", does the Kingston A2000 has a termal plate?

Comment: It does not have that, but it also does not need it. The kingston A2000 is an ssd where Kingston cheaped out on the controllers speed, and therefore power consumption and heat output

Comment: Some ssd's indeed need a thermal plate, but the A2000 can live with the minimal of minimal airflow (if you see a fan in the laptop, probably ok)

Comment: Finally, I got an offer from Dell but I'm pretty confused. They offer SSDR,1TB,P34,80S2,HYNIX,PC711 for the price of 250 EUR. What do you think?

Also, as you may see in the picture, a screw is missing. I asked DELL for missing parts and they offered me the following:
- SCR,M2X2,FLH,MSCR,NI-PLTD
- PLT,SSD 2280/2230,W/PAD,BM15/P
Maybe can you explain me what these parts are, so I can but them elsewhere if DELL does not want to sell me them if I don't want to buy the SSD.

Comment: Don't buy the ssd from Dell, you can still get the screw I hope. €250 is also way too expensive for a 1TB SSD

Comment: I indeed could order the missing parts for inserting SSD and HDD (see my other post). All costs around 55 EUR. Dell makes good business selling notebooks with missing parts...

Comment: Conclusion: if you need a new pc, don't get a dell :)